# I called a bat file from jar , after execution I want the control returned to the jar , how to do that?

Tags: batch-file, jar, runtime

Used below command to execute bat from jar :
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start TC1.bat");

Comment: I have no way of testing this (hence it being a comment instead of an answer), but try changing `start` to `call`, since `call` should return control upon completion while `start` does not.

Comment: Thanks . Will try that . Meanwhile , I changed the workflow in such a way that I wasn't dependant on that.